# 403 error when query param contains 2 byte character?

Tags: django, unicode, utf-8

I am testing an API constucted via django views.py/urls.py format:

where HttpResponse in views.py just returns filter_param, which is captured by some regex pattern defined in urls.py.

I input some UTF-8 encoded char to test what is being captured by API, and receive an error in *cases where the char requires more than one byte to encode.*

ex v1/.../filter/'%C2%A9'/
Returns: 403 Forbidden, expected copyright char

But v1/.../filter/'%7E%7E'/
Returns: ~~

Therefore I know that this is not an issue of improperly formed regex.

I am on python 2.x, and I read that python v2 only understands UTF-16. I tried this (%00%A9) query instead and received a not found error.

Server is running Apache. I am new to django and unfamiliar with URI encoding standards, so any knowledge about the origin of this error would be helpful.

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  url(r'^...some_path/(?P<filter_type>.*)/(?P<filter_by>[\w\d@\.-\%]+)/$',
    'views.get_function'
    ),...)
```

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py` file?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte edited question body to include relevant line